# Прием JSON файла на spring

Tags: java, json, spring

На сервер поступает JSON-файл, я его получил с поморью `@RequestMapping`. Как мне сохранить его в java-объект класса location ?

```
@RestController
public class contrl {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<location> set(@RequestBody location location)
    {


            return new ResponseEntity<location>(location, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}


public class location {
    List<location> ver;
    private int DevID;
    private double Lat;
    private double Long;
    private double Tm;
    private int LocID;

    public List<location> getver() {
        return ver;
    }


    public void setver(List<location> ver) {
        this.ver = ver;
    }

    public int getDevID() {
        return DevID;
    }

    public void setDevID(int DevID) {
            this.DevID = DevID;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return Lat;
     }
    public void setLat(double Lat) {
        this.Lat = Lat;
    }
    public double getLong() {
        return Long;
    }
    public void setLong(double Long) {
        this.Long = Long;
    }
    public double getTm() {
        return Tm;
    }
    public void setTm(double Tm) {
        this.Tm = Tm;
    }
    public int getLocID() {
        return LocID;
    }

    public void setLocID(int LocID) {
        this.LocID = LocID;
    }

}
```

Comment: Какого другого?

Comment: Ну да мне нужно его сохранить как обьект в location, я уже просмотрел кучу гайдов и про библиотеки GSON и Jackson, но серьезно не могу понять, как это сделать.

Comment: Приведённый код не работает?

Comment: Ну когда я добави  loc.getLat();
        loc.getver();
        loc.getLat();
        loc.getLong();
        loc.getDevID();
        loc.getTm();
        loc.getLocID();                                                                                             он вывел новый location но не присвоил им значения которые я отправил в POST

Comment: Что такое `loc`? Не вижу его в коде.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json") public ResponseEntity<location> set(@RequestBody location input) {
location loc = new location();
 loc.getLat(); loc.getver();                                                           loc.getLat();                                                                      
loc.getLong();                                                            loc.getDevID();                                                      loc.getTm(); loc.getLocID();
return new ResponseEntity<location>(input, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

Comment: Редактируйте вопрос, разбирать код в комментарии очень тяжело. Насколько я вижу, вы просто создали оператором `new` новый объект класса `location`, данным в нём появится неоткуда. Почему бы вам не поискать их в `input`?

Comment: в каком именно ? я новичок в java в принципе не очень дохожу, что надо добавить к коду в вопросе чтобы он это принял и сохранил

Comment: У вас метод принимает аргумент `input` типа `location`, в нём. Ну и совет, не беритесь за Spring, JavaEE или мобильную разработку до тех пора, пока не освоите Java Core.

Comment: Все заработало когда поменял последовательность значений в запросе на такую {
"ver": 1,
"long": 37.754567,
"devID": 1234,
"lat": 55.345616,
"tm": 35,
"locID": 123
}                                                                                                      откуда она взялась именно такая непонятно